# Value of the PDE at given position and time

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the value of the following PDE at $x=3$; $t=2$; $u(3,2)$

$$\frac{du}{dt} = (1-t)\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial^2{x}}$$

on the domain $-\infty< x < \infty$, $t\ge0$

For the given boundary conditions

$$u(x,0) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

I have tried solving using fourier trasnform but apparently there is a method to get the value without having to solve for the complete solution ?

Comment: Can't you just separate the variables and solve?

Comment: The equation $\frac{du}{dt} = (1-t)\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial^2{t}}$ doesn't seem to exhibit any dependence on the variable $x$.  Wassup?  Cheers!

Comment: made the change, thanks !

Comment: for seperation of variables i need a homoeneous sub-system in one direction. Since its domian extends to infinity Fourier transform is a good way to solve

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get a convolution integral that solves the problem via fourier transform, namely

$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t(2-t)}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{1 + (x-y)^2} \right)\exp\left[{\frac{-y^2}{2t(2-t)}}\right]\, dy$$

It is readily seen, however, that this solution only exists for $0<t<2$, so the evaluation of the solution at $u(3,2)$ does not exist. Numerical evidence, however, seems to suggest that

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 2^-} u(3,t) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 2^-}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t(2-t)}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{1 + (3-y)^2} \right)\exp\left[{\frac{-y^2}{2t(2-t)}}\right]\, dy = 1/10$$

EDIT: Note that $u(x,t) = u(x,2-t)$ from the above solution, so that it is clear that

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} u(x,t) = u(x,0) = u(x,2) = \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Hence we can compute the limit explicitly to be

$$\lim_{t->2^-}u(3,t) = \dfrac{1}{10}$$

Comment: Solving it via typical methods: Fourier transform the problem and the IC and one obtains $U(s,t) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-|s|}e^{s^2\left(\frac{t^2}{2} - t\right)}$ as the Fourier transform of the solution. Now just invoke the convolution theorem and you have it, only computing the IFT of each piece in the integral.

Comment: You can change the $\approx$ by $=$ ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I was actually thinking that there’s some kind of property with the PDE that $u(x,0) = u(x,2)$, as the solution close to 2 looks very much like the initial condition.

Comment: Actually, that is now obvious to me. I may edit my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @DaveNine's answer, it is possible to compute exactly
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t(2-t)}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{1 + (3-y)^2} \right)\exp\left[{\frac{-y^2}{2t(2-t)}}\right]\, dy $$
A CAS gives
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-k^2 y^2}}{1+(3-y)^2}\,dy=\frac{\pi }{2}  e^{-(8+6 i) k^2} \left(e^{12 i k^2} \text{erfc}((1+3 i) k)+i\,
   \text{erfi}((3+i) k)+1\right)$$ Then
$$f(t)=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{\frac{4-3 i}{(t-2) t}} \left(-\text{erf}\left((1+3
   i) \sqrt{\frac{1}{4 t-2 t^2}}\right)+i e^{\frac{6 i}{(t-2) t}}
   \text{erfi}\left((3+i) \sqrt{\frac{1}{4 t-2 t^2}}\right)+e^{\frac{6 i}{(t-2)
   t}}+1\right)}{2 \sqrt{(2-t) t}}$$

Let $t=2-10^{-k}$ and get the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & f\left(2-10^{-k}\right) \\
 1 & 0.10530808447 \\
 2 & 0.10052118333 \\
 3 & 0.10005201191 \\
 4 & 0.10000520012 \\
 5 & 0.10000052000 \\
 6 & 0.10000005200 \\
 7 & 0.10000000520 \\
 8 & 0.10000000052
\end{array}
\right)$$

Expanding $f(t)$ as series around $t=2$, 
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{10}-\frac{13 (t-2)}{250}+\frac{149 (t-2)^2}{12500}+\frac{132
   (t-2)^3}{15625}-\frac{68121 (t-2)^4}{3125000}+O\left((t-2)^5\right)$$